# How to stop bluetooth from activating every time Mac wakes up?

Tags: audio, sleep-wake, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth speaker that I use occasionally, but not often.  A few weeks ago I decided it was time to upgrade my Mid-2011 iMac from Mavericks, to Sierra (not High Sierra).  Ever since then, the BT speaker connects itself as my Mac's audio device every time the machine wakes up from sleep.  This is very annoying... if I disconnect a device, I expect it to stay disconnected unless I manually connect it.  Why does this keep happening and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because it's been paired with the mac. Unpair the device.

> Remove a Bluetooth device from your Mac
>   If you want to remove (unpair) a Bluetooth device from your Mac's device list, follow these steps:
>   Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Bluetooth.
>   Hover the pointer over the device you want to remove, then click the button Cancel button that appears next to the device's name.

***After you remove a Bluetooth device, you'll have to repeat the pairing process if you want to use it again.***

Comment: I don't want to unpair, I should have been clear about that.  This problem never happened in Mavericks with years of it being paired to this same speaker.

Comment: I don't think there is any way around this other than unpairing or turning off the device.

Comment: So it happens to you as well? I guess this is some new feature they have added since Mavericks?  What an incredibly obnoxious thing to do to their users.  I expect my computer to respect the audio device settings I choose.

Comment: I guess at this time anyway, the only solution to this is in fact to unpair, and re-pair any time I want to use the device.  I think this is completely lame and pathetic of Apple, especially since it worked perfectly fine in Mavericks.  But, such is life... I'm going to accept this answer unless someone comes along with something better that doesn't require unpairing.